# Hahn Banach extensions.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider the normed linear space $R^2$ equipped with the norm given by $||(x,y)||=|x|+|y|$ and the subspace $X=\{(x,y)\in R^2 : x=y\}.$ Let $f(x,y)=3x$ on $X$. Then what is the Hahn Banach extension of $f$.?

I have gone through different books and dufferent methods and idea of how to find such extensions. But stil not comfortable with it. Could you please help me understand a general method? Is there any general idea? Is the norm of $f \ 3?$. A similar question is there in one book but there norm of $f$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$.

Comment: Why do you think it is unique?

Comment: I am getting unique extension as $g(x,y)=\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{3y}{2}$.

Comment: But I don't know whether it is correct or not.

Comment: another extension is $g(x,y)=3x$

Comment: How to find such extensions?